# Specify read only fields for lightning:recordForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, read-only, lightning-record-form

On the Case object, I have a lightning component that displays only the fields of interest depending on the Status of the case.  I have a separate `Change_Status_To__c` dependent picklist that actually controls what options are available to the user for updating the status (and automation in the backend actually changes the status).

I'm currently using `lightning:recordForm` to display the relevant fields, and would like to display just the `Status` field as read only.  Is there anyway to single out/access this field and set it as read only?

All other fields should be editable, and would like to avoid using `lightning:recordEditForm` if possible

Comment: How are you passing fields to the recordform component is it through fields or reading fields from layout?.

Comment: Through `fields`.  I'm updating them dynamically based on the current `Status`, and I basically use an `aura:if` to turn off / on the component to load the fields properly.  Otherwise there's weird behavior that the new fields just add on to the existing fields on the `recordForm` component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to make a field read only specifically while using [`lightning:recordForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/documentation). It's either all fields or none which you could display as read only depending on the mode selected. The component operates based on the field level security, so if a field is not read only for a User, you cannot make one as read only on the component. Additionally there's not much support for client side validation on this component.

Your only option here as far as I can say is to utilize [`lightning:recordEditForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/documentation).

Comment: if for pulling fields layout is used and in the layout if we mark the field read only will that not work?

Comment: I can't use the layout option because the fields are being adjust dynamically based on what status we're currently on

Comment: @JayantDas That's what I figured, and it's good to get a consensus that `lightning:recordEditForm` is the only way to go

Comment: @BrianMiller - if you are using filelds then jayant's answer is perfect

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Fields / layoutType attributes for displaying the Fields .
My suggestion would be to take out Status field from the above fields/Layout and display it using lightning:outputField. 
You're not submitting it as an editable form field anyways.

Comment: You can't use `lightning:outputField` in `lightning:recordForm`.  Looks like I'll need to switch to `lightning:recordEditForm`

Comment: I meant using the lightning:outputField outside the lightning:recordForm. But then, you'll have to fetch its value.
You can also use Both lightning:recordEditForm and lightning:recordForm in the same page to achieve it. That way your existing code works as it is. But yeah, if you can switch/convert to lightning:recordEditForm, then its the best bet.